# Comparing numbers and receiving binary output in R

Tags: r, math, numbers, compare, complex-numbers

So what I am attempting to do may be quite rudimentary, so please excuse my ignorance.

I have a matrix made up of two columns of fold changes:

```
mat<-matrix(rexp(10, rate=.1), ncol=2)
colnames(mat)<-c("ctr","tst")
mat
            ctr       tst
[1,]  3.80024188  3.450514
[2,]  3.19933014  5.315761
[3,]  0.01122948  4.398819
[4,] 21.86070191 26.109626
[5,]  5.38260987  1.678203
```

What I would like to do is add a third column that contains a binary "1" or "0" value as an output of comparing the fold change in the ctr column with the tst column, with some provided tolerance, such as 0.75 for example.

So basically the value in the new column of mat[1,3], which compares mat[1,1] and mat[1,2], would be a "0" (less than 0.75 apart) while mat[3,3] comparing mat[3,1] and mat[3,2] would contain a value of "1" (more than 0.75 apart).

Additionally (and this is where it gets tricky for me) I need to incorporate a way of comparing "Inf" and "-Inf' values to regular numbers, as some of my fold changes come out to "Inf" or "-Inf".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably specify what you expect to happen when `Inf` and `-Inf` are compared with actual values. Always a 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a comparison function that returns `TRUE` whenever the two inputs are either no more than 0.75 apart, or both `Inf`, or both `-Inf`:

```
compare <- function(xx) {
    if ( (xx[1]==Inf & xx[2]==Inf) | (xx[1]==-Inf & xx[2]==-Inf) ) {
        TRUE
    } else {
        abs(diff(xx))<=0.75
    }
}
```

Then create a test matrix and `apply` this function (taking its logical inverse using `!` for the nonstandard mapping of `TRUE` to 0 and `FALSE` to 1):

```
> set.seed(1)
> mat <- rbind(matrix(rexp(10, rate=.1), ncol=2),c(1,Inf),c(-Inf,0),c(Inf,Inf),c(Inf,-Inf),c(-Inf,-Inf))
> colnames(mat)<-c("ctr","tst")
> 
> cbind(mat,!apply(mat,1,compare))
            ctr       tst  
 [1,]  7.551818 28.949685 1
 [2,] 11.816428 12.295621 0
 [3,]  1.457067  5.396828 1
 [4,]  1.397953  9.565675 1
 [5,]  4.360686  1.470460 1
 [6,]  1.000000       Inf 1
 [7,]      -Inf  0.000000 1
 [8,]       Inf       Inf 0
 [9,]       Inf      -Inf 1
[10,]      -Inf      -Inf 0
>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much Stephan.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot in the dark:

```
set.seed(123)
mat<-matrix(rexp(10, rate=.1), ncol=2)
colnames(mat)<-c("ctr","tst")
#Add some Inf examples
mat[4,1] <- Inf
mat[2,2] <- -Inf
mat <- cbind(mat,(abs(mat[,1] - mat[,2]) >= 0.75) + 0L)
mat

##            ctr        tst  
##[1,]  8.4345726  3.1650122 1
##[2,]  5.7661027       -Inf 1
##[3,] 13.2905487  1.4526680 1
##[4,]        Inf 27.2623646 1
##[5,]  0.5621098  0.2915345 0
```